# Louvain algorithm: self-loop weight is double?

Tags: graphs

In the 2nd phase of [the Louvain algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1502), self-loops are given by the sum of all the intra-community weights. I'm wondering from their own figure, why all of the self-loops seem to have `2w` weights, rather than `w`. Note in the blue community for instance: 2 intra-community edges, self loop has weight 4.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more context (a reference for this algorithm, an explanation of what the goal is)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every edge has the same weight, which it contributes to each endpoint. When both endpoints are in the same cluster, the edge counts twice towards that cluster. Then they are in different clusters, the edge counts once towards each of the two clusters. So each edge has the same overall contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they calculate the total intra-community weight by considering the intra-community weight leaving every single node in the community, and then summing these. This sums all intra-community edges double.

Comment: But this does not answer my question. I'm aware they are counting it twice, but why would that be the case? And why count the edge weight twice for intra-community, and not inter-community?

Comment: They only do it when contracting an edge - it is a convention. The algorithm is a heuristic, and hence I don't expect a clear motivation for choosing this convention.