# Louvain algorithm: self-loop weight calculations for super-node

Tags: algorithms, graphs

In the Louvain algorithm, a super node is created in the second phase with self-loops from the sum of intra-community edges. According to the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476.pdf) and the [lecture CS224W](https://youtu.be/0zuiLBOIcsw?t=692), self-loop edges are counted with a factor of 1, while edges between different nodes of the same community are counted with a factor of 2, and inter-community edges are summed up with a factor of 1.

However, when using [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/4859ed12f719f9c9581bbb7e0e9c3d2c4843ee14/networkx/algorithms/community/louvain.py#L318) and [CDLib](https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain/blob/638804ae636dc65306900ef6518ca0a1c9202566/community/community_louvain.py#L373), all edges are counted with a factor of 1. Additionally, if we calculate modularity before merging (after phase 1 is finished) and after merging, the results seem more consistent if all edges are counted with a factor of 1.

My calculations for the second pass of the algorithm show that when we evaluate the weight of the self-loop of the super-node, we should count each intra-edge weight with a factor of 1. This approach results in $Q(C)$ remaining the same and seems more coherent than using a factor of 2 for intra-edges (excluding self-loops).

Below are the calculations and picture of Figure 1 visualization of the steps of the algorithm from original paper.

[image]

The formulas from the original paper are:

- $m = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}A_{ij}$.

  Given this formula, I consider that self-loop's weight is counted twice in degree calculation, and its also often default convention for undirected graphs.
- $Q(C) = \frac{1}{2m} \displaystyle\sum_{ij \in C} \left[ A_{ij} - \frac{k_i k_j}{2m} \right]$

  or lets rather calculate this equivalent expression  $Q(C) = \frac{\sum_{in}}{m} - [\frac{\sum_{tot}}{2m}]^2$, where $\sum_{in}$ - total weight sum of edges in community $C$, and $\sum_{tot}$ - total degree sum of nodes in community $C$.

Here are my calculations for 2nd pass that is depicted at the picture (two vertices at the top (green and blue) are form first community $C_1$, two others (red and light-blue) are in $C_2$):

$m_{before} = 14+4+4+1+1+1+16+3+2 = 46$

$degree(green) = 14*2 + 4 + 1 + 1 = 34$

$degree(blue) = 4*2 + 4 + 1 = 13$

$degree(red) = 16*2 + 3 + 1 = 36$

$degree(light$-$blue) = 2*2 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 9$

$Q_{before} (C_1) = \frac{14+4+4}{46} - [\frac{34+13}{92}]^2 \approx 0.217$

$Q_{before} (C_2) = \frac{16+3+2}{46} - [\frac{36+9}{92}]^2 \approx 0.217$

1. Count intra-community edges with factor 2 for different nodes

   $m_{after} = 26+24+3 = 53$

   $degree(green) = 26*2 + 3 = 55$

   $degree(light$-$blue) = 24*2 + 3 = 51$

   $Q_{after} (C_1) = \frac{26}{53} - [\frac{55}{106}]^2 \approx 0.221$

   $Q_{after} (C_2) = \frac{24}{53} - [\frac{51}{106}]^2 \approx 0.221$
2. Count intra-community edges with factor 1 for different nodes

   We have graph with this edges list: [(0,0,22), (0, 1, 3), (1, 1, 21)]

   $m_{after} = 22 + 3 + 21 = 46$

   $degree(green) = 22*2 + 3 = 47$

   $degree(light$-$blue) = 21*2 + 3 = 45$

   $Q_{after} (C_1) = \frac{22}{46} - [\frac{47}{92}]^2 \approx 0.217$

   $Q_{after} (C_2) = \frac{21}{46} - [\frac{45}{92}]^2 \approx 0.217$

So, if we use factor 1 for intra-edges $Q(C)$ will remain the same. However, the original paper and CS224W use a factor of 2 for intra-edges. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

PS. I am aware of similar question here [Louvain algorithm: self-loop weight is double?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113438/louvain-algorithm-self-loop-weight-is-double). But there are answers that do not answer my question.